# Data from a SQL database to an array for a shopping cart

Tags: php, sql, session, shopping-cart

I'm trying to pass data I've retrieved from my SQL Database to a `$_SESSION` array for a shopping cart to be displayed to the user. I don't think the information is actually getting passed over, the program ends up displaying but it gives me blank fields. For reference, I'm trying to pass over data through multiple PHP files. Additionally, once I pass the information over, I'm unsure how I would loop said $_SESSION array the user to add multiple items.

I'm not sure if the issue is through my `include()` with my `index`, or maybe my `form action` in the `product_list`. But somewhere either the data isn't passing or it doesn't work the way I think it does.

This is the code within my `product_list` where the data is initially sent

```
foreach ($products as $product)  : ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $product['productID']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $product['productName']; ?></td>
                    <td class="right"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
                    <td><form action="../Cart/index.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action"
                               value="add_product">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_name"
                               value="<?php echo $product['productName'];?>"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_price"
                               value ="<?php echo $product['price'];?>">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
                    <?php endforeach;
```

This is the code within my `index` where the the shopping cart is included

```
if ($action == 'add_product') 
{   

    include('../Cart/index.php');
}
```

This is my code within the ```index within the shopping cart path

```
$action = 'add_to_cart';


if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if($action == 'add_to_cart')
{
    $cart_product_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'product_name');
    $cart_product_price = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'product_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
    $product = array('price' => $cart_product_price, 'name' => $cart_product_name);
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $product; 
   include('cart_view.php');
}
```

And this is where the `$_SESSION` array should be displaying

```
<main>
        <h1>Your Cart</h1>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <?php
            print_r($_SESSION['cart'][0]);
        ?>
```

What's actually being displayed is this `Array ( [price] => [name] => )`

Comment: what does enabling error reporting reveal on the php side of things?

Comment: I don't know if I'm implementing error reporting wrong but I'm not getting anything to show up. @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that your input names are incorrect. Every product name input is currently name="product_name", likewise for product_price. You need to pass these through as an array, or each with their own unique key. Otherwise you get one single post value for product_name and product_price - which will be whatever the last inputs with those names are in the form.

You can pass them as an array by doing name="product_name[]" and then your post will contain an array of all those values, in the order that they appear in the form.

Next, you say your output is currently Array ( [price] => [name] => ). This indicates to me that your session is in fact working, because you have keys in that array. So actually setting the session is not the problem. So then you go back to where the session is being set, and see that you are using INPUT_GET in your filter_input parameters - but you are receiving POST values. Your parameter should not be INPUT_GET, it should be INPUT_POST.

Once you get all that cleared up you're still going to have a problem, because the inputs for product_name and product_price are going to be arrays with multiple values. You need to loop through them to assemble the final array that gets set to the session. I'll leave that to you to explore, because that will look far different than what you currently have going on in your add_to_cart action.

Comment: I had thought that the value would be what appears when the $_Session array would be the $product['productName'] based off my database.  by passing them each with their each unique key, do you mean something like this?

<input type="hidden" name="product['.$product['productID'].']name" value="'.$product['productName'].'">

Thank you for the clarification on the SESSION and the filter_input parameters. I'll give it a go, but could you give me some general tips in what direction I should go by either passing it an array through product_name[] or unique key to updating the SESSION array?